# iOS dismissing a view controller doesn't release memory

Tags: ios, memory-management, memory-leaks, weak-references, strong-references

I know it's all with the weak strong reference when presenting the viewController in the parent view ... correct me please if I'm wrong

this is an example how I do it

```
let viewHolder = viewClass()

func presentView()  {
    self.present(viewHolder, animated: true) {

    }
}
```

see my memory monitor **only** from open and dismiss the same view over and over

[image]
I have tried this

```
weak var viewHolder = viewClass()

func presentView()  {
    self.present(viewHolder!, animated: true) {

    }
}
```

but this would give me a crash

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

and dismiss the viewClass this way (inside itself off)

```
func dismissPage()  {
    self.dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

any help would be appreciated
 thanks

Comment: Show the declaration of `viewClass`. Also explain how the presented view is dismissed.

Comment: @matt thanks for replaying, I updated my question please see the end  for the dismissing part. about the declaring `viewClass`, not sure what you mean ? see the question, there was a typo from my side and I corrected it .

Comment: You have a class called `viewClass`. Show it. Show your code! We can’t intuit by magic what is causing the retain cycle. Show us your code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might not be in the `viewClass`. You are declaring `let viewHolder = viewClass()` in your initial class. So when you dismiss the controller, that variable still exists. Do you need to keep a reference to it? If not, you can easily allocate it when needs to be displayed and when you dismiss it, the memory is going to be freed:

```
func presentView()  {
     // instead of saving viewHolder as an instance variable, you declare it locally
    let viewHolder = viewClass()
    self.present(viewHolder, animated: true) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Use deint method and check weather it is called or not after dismiss your viewcontroller.
2. if your using any kind of blocks or closure to work done then use [weak self] in side your closure.
3. your can also make nil your property/delegate/variable when viewDidDisappeared only if after there is no view controller will be presented or pushed